# adding a constant to tuple list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So I have a list of tuples and would like to do a for each over the list of tuple and add the constant to the list

something like this

```
convertingList :: (Int,Int)->[(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
convertingList (a,b) list = [(x,y) | (c,d) <- list] where x = a + c   y = b + d
```

and i get the error c and d are not in scope , how can i solve this problem?
Variable not in scope: c :: Int
Variable not in scope: d :: Int

Is there a better function I can use, maybe with map ?
Thx for the help

Comment: Which constant do you want to add to what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `where` is scoped *outside* the list comprehension. Outside the list comprehension `c` and `d` are indeed *not* defined.

But I think you make this problem too compilcated. You can simply put the addition in the head of the list comprehension:

```
convertingList :: (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
convertingList (a,b) list = [(a + c, b + d) | (c,d) <- list]
```

or you could use a `let` expression:

```
convertingList :: (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
convertingList (a,b) list = [let x = a+c; y = b+d in (x, y) | (c,d) <- list]
```

or like [@M.Aroosi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52875935/adding-a-constant-to-tuple-list/52876042?noredirect=1#comment92667480_52876042) says, we can move the `let`s (without `in`!) to the body part of the list comprehension:

```
convertingList :: (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
convertingList (a,b) list = [ (x, y) | (c,d) <- list, let x = a+c, let y = b+d]
```

An alterantive could be to define a mapping function that adds `a` and `b` to the elements, like:

```
convertingList :: (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
convertingList (a,b) = map f
    where f (c, d) = (a+c, b+d)
```

or with [**`(***) :: Arrow a => a b c -> a b' c' -> a (b, b') (c, c')`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:-42--42--42-):

```
import Control.Arrow((***))

convertingList :: (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
convertingList (a,b) = map ((***) (a+) (b+))
```

Comment: Another option is `[(x, y) | (c,d) <- list, let x = a+c, let y = b+d]`